# Dynamic image list in Easy Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, imagelist, vichuploaderbundle, symfony2-easyadmin

I wanna create dynamic image list, user should be able to add unlimited number of images. I'm using vich uploader extension. How to do it in some easy way?

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow this guide?
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/vichuploaderbundle.html

Instead of having a Product entity as in the example you can have an Image entity. Then you map the Image entity to a Gallery entity. After that you probably need to add some kind of custom templates to easyadmin.